# how to load json in extjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, extjs

i am loading the values coming from web service but i get following error message.
ChatStore.data.items[i] is undefined.

Mapping code for extjs is

```
ChatStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
         storeId: 'ChatStore1',
         fields: [
                    {name: "pic_url", mapping: "sender_pic_url"}, 
                   {name: "first_name", mapping: "first_name"},
                    {name: "last_name", mapping: "last_name"},
                    {name: "message_text", mapping: "message_text"},
                    {name: "time", mapping: "time"}

                ]        

     });
```

code for loading data from webservice

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'webservice call',
         params: Ext.encode('{"sender_user_id":"' + suid + '","receiver_user_id":"' + ruid + '"}'),
         headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
        success: function (result, request) {

            retData = (result.responseText);
            alert(retData);
             retData = eval("(" + retData + ")");
             if (retData.status == 'success') {


                 //ChatStore.loadData(retData.result.messages);
                 //ChatStore.loadData(retData.result);
                 for (var i = 0; i < retData.result.messages.length; i++) {
                     if (retData.result.messages[i].message_from == "YES") {

                         ChatStore.data.items[i].data.pic_url = retData.result.sender_pic_url;
                         ChatStore.data.items[i].data.first_name = retData.result.sender_name;


                    }
                     else {
                        ChatStore.data.items[i].data.pic_url = retData.result.receiver_pic_url;
                         ChatStore.data.items[i].data.first_name = retData.result.reciever_name;
                    } 

                     ChatStore.data.items[i].data.message_text = retData.result.messages[i].message_text;
                    ChatStore.data.items[i].data.time = retData.result.messages[i].time;

                }
                // ChatPanel.render('divchat');

                 messagePanel.hide();
                ChatPanel.show();
            }


             else { alert('error loading first radius'); }

         },
        failure: function (result, request) {

             alert("Error: " + result.statusText);
         }

         });  
return false;
}
```

My webservice result is:-----

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Messages are listing below",
    "result": {
        "sender_name": "Paul",
        "reciever_name": "Clay",
        "sender_pic_url": "Images/f1.jpg",
        "receiver_pic_url": "Images/f2.jpg",
        "messages": [
            {
                "message_from": "YES",
                "message_text": "hi, how r u?",
                "time": "12:00am"
            },
            {
                "message_from": "NO",
                "message_text": "hi, where are you?",
                "time": "1:00am"
            },
            {
                "message_from": "NO",
                "message_text": "Dear, you are invited for the meeting",
                "time": "2:00am"
            },
            {
                "message_from": "YES",
                "message_text": "hi, how r u?",
                "time": "12:00am"
            },
            {
                "message_from": "NO",
                "message_text": "hi, where are you?",
                "time": "1:00am"
            },
            {
                "message_from": "NO",
                "message_text": "Dear, you are invited for the meeting",
                "time": "2:00am"
            },
            {
                "message_from": "NO",
                "message_text": "Ya ill be there",
                "time": "2:00am"
            },
            {
                "message_from": "NO",
                "message_text": "at what time party starts",
                "time": "2:00am"
            },
            {
                "message_from": "YES",
                "message_text": "6Oclock in the evening",
                "time": "2:00am"
            },
            {
                "message_from": "NO",
                "message_text": "Who will the chief guest",
                "time": "2:00am"
            },
            {
                "message_from": "YES",
                "message_text": "our city mayor",
                "time": "2:00am"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

i dont know where the things go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assign items to the store.items array. First of all it's undefined. Second, it's not correct approach overall.

You need either to specify Json proxy object in the store and then store will load itself automatically and all items will be populated without any special code, or

You need to use store.add() function to add new items to the store.

From your code looks like you're using store.load() method, no? Can you post more code on how exactly you load data and how you're communication with the server looks like.

Comment: thanks.. i upadate my code here...
i am tested with debugger  ChatStore.data.items[i].data.pic_url this get correct value but i dont know how to load in store...

Comment: Don't need to do all this. Check proxy property for the store. This is where you specify that you have Json proxy and URL to your server. Then you just call store.load() and it will do Ajax request by itself and you get your data in the store automatically.

Comment: i know store.load method but i am getting pic_url and name at one time and i have to map with sender_pic and receiver pic and use in dataview at 11 time. I.e based on webservice

Comment: ok. then in order to access and change items inside the store use store.getAt(i) to get a model and then set('property_name') to change the field. Or look at each() method for store. Don't go directly to data.items.

Comment: ChatStore.data.items[i].data.pic_url = retData.result.sender_pic_url;
 this method is useful or not...
what can i use now

Comment: No. Try ChatStore.getAt(i).set('pic_url', retData.result.sender_pic_url)

Comment: after using this ....
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined
this msg display in debugger